# Python - Get average RGB Components of Image Regions

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I need to calculate the average Red, Green & Blue color component values for an image. The image is not necessarily square. It could be rectangular as well.

The image is divided into 4 quadrants and each quadrant is further divided into 2 triangular regions, giving total of 8 regions in the image (P1 - P8) as such

```
# -------------------------
# - Q1        +        Q2 -   
# -        P8 + P1        -
# -      P7   +    P2     -
# -+++++++++++++++++++++++-
# -      P6   +    P3     -
# -        P5 + P4        -
# - Q4        +        Q3 -
# -------------------------
```

So far I have managed to get the image (primary monitor screenshot) and convert the rgb values to a numpy array.

From there I am not sure of the best way to get the triangular regions as I need this operation to be done atleast 3 times a second.

Any ideas?

```
import subprocess
import numpy
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

#GET THE PRIMARY MONITOR RESOLUTION
output = subprocess.Popen('xrandr | grep "\*" | cut -d" " -f4',shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
primary_monitor_x = output.split("\n")[0].split("x")[0].strip()
primary_monitor_y = output.split("\n")[0].split("x")[1].strip()
print "primary monitor X = " + primary_monitor_x + "px"
print "primary monitor Y = " + primary_monitor_y + "px"

print ""
print ""

x_max = int(primary_monitor_x)
y_max = int(primary_monitor_y)

#GET SCREEN IMAGE IN A PIL IMAGE
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,x_max,  y_max))
#CONVERT IMAGE TO RGB MODE
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

#CONVERT IMAGE TO NUMPY 2D ARRAY WITH EACH ELEMENT AS PIXEL RGB TUPLE
img_rgb_array = numpy.array(rgb_im);

#THE SCREEN IS DIVIDED INTO 8 PARTS. FOR EACH PART, THE AVERAGE VALUE
#OF RED, GREEN, BLUE COLOR COMPONENT WILL BE CALCULATED
# -------------------------
# - Q1        +        Q2 -   
# -        P8 + P1        -
# -      P7   +    P2     -
# -+++++++++++++++++++++++-
# -      P6   +    P3     -
# -        P5 + P4        -
# - Q4        +        Q3 -
# -------------------------

#SLICE THE IMAGE RGB ARRAY INTO 4 SMALLER QUADRANT ARRAYS
img_rgb_arraq_q1 = img_rgb_array[0:(y_max/2), 0:(x_max/2)]
img_rgb_arraq_q2 = img_rgb_array[0:(y_max/2), (x_max/2):x_max]
img_rgb_arraq_q3 = img_rgb_array[(y_max/2):y_max, (x_max/2):x_max]
img_rgb_arraq_q4 = img_rgb_array[(y_max/2):y_max, 0:(x_max/2)]
```

Comment: How do you decide which elements go into the upper/lower triangular parts? In particular if the quadrant is not square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a square Q2Q4 you could do something like

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
a = np.arange(n**2).reshape((n,n))

idx = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: i+j<n, (n,n))
# use i+j<n-1 if the diagonal should go to the lower triangular

a_upper = a.copy()
a_upper[np.logical_not(idx)] = 0

a_lower = a.copy()
a_lower[idx] = 0

print a_upper
print a_lower
```

For the more general case of non-square matrices I'm not sure how you would like to place your "diagonal". Maybe something like

```
n, m = 3,5
a = np.arange(n*m).reshape((n,m))

idx = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: i/(n-1.) + j/(m-1.) <= 1, (n,m))

a_upper = a.copy()
a_upper[np.logical_not(idx)] = 0

a_lower = a.copy()
a_lower[idx] = 0

print a_upper
print a_lower
```

is what you want?

Q1/Q3 would just needed to be rotated before/after.

For efficiency: The most expensive part is probably the creation of the `idx` array. However that can be reused and does not have to be created every time you need the separation.

Comment: Thanks! i'm not very proficient with python so I tried this in the interpreter and its exactly what I am looking for. Could you explain what `np.formfunction` does?

Comment: [np.fromfunction](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) is constructing an array from the function given as the first argument which itself calculates the array elements using their indices.

Comment: I just noticed that you obviously want to rotate Q1 and Q3 and not transpose it. I corrected that in the answer.

Comment: Yep. I figured the rotation part. Thanks, for the explanation on lambda!